# image_mousedown event giving strange coordinates

Tags: vba, excel, activex, excel-2016

I am working on retrieving the location of mouse clicks on charts, in the units of the chart axes. The mousedown event applied to chart objects returns coordinates relative to the origin of the chart object in px (I believe), but I need to know where the click falls within the plot area itself. To get around this I am overlaying ActiveX images, which are transparent, over the plot area of my charts. This way the mousedown event is relative to the image. By placing its origin on the chart axes origin I can transform the returned X/Y to chart units simply by knowing the image .height & .width properties.

This works for one of the images and I can confirm it returns X/Y which are (0,0) at the axis origin. The second image also returns (0,0) at the origin, but the X/Y values returned from mousedown scale up 32x faster than the first as I move away from the axes origin. Both images have the same .height & .width and so the second image starts returning X/Y values larger than its own size not far from the image origin.

I appreciate that I can correct this problem by dividing the mousedown X/Y by a factor of 32, but would really prefer to understand why they are scaling up faster.

Please see a copy of my code for each image mousedown event as well as pictures of the image properties-to confirm their properties are the same-attached.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As _
  Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  Dim imH As Single

  Image1.Visible = False
  imH = Image1.Height
  MsgBox Y/imH
  Image1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Image2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As _
  Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  Dim imH As Single

  Image2.Visible = False
  imH = Image2.Height
  MsgBox Y/imH
  Image2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

image properties

[image]

Comment: @cyboashu isn't `Image.Height` measured in *twips* (15px units)?

Comment: @cyboashu since both image use the same units for .Height and use the same units for X/Y, they should still scale the same.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, honestly couldn't find any source for 15px. So it  may be true.  ObjectBrowser doesn't even have a Height/Width property. :)

Comment: @fallengyro , I read your post wrong.